# replace content along with newline

Tags: batch-file, newline

I am using bat script to replace content from another bat file. along with that, I want to add newline but the "\n" is reflecting instead of newline in outfile.bat

%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command "(gc outfile.txt) -replace '
svn', '**\n**C:\Projects\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe' | Out-File -encoding default outfile.bat"

can somebody help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a backtick instead of a backward slash, and the replacement string containing it, should be double quoted instead of single quoted. As those double quotes would be nested within a double quoted command, you need to escape those with a backslash for cmd.exe to pass them to powershell.exe as needed:

```sh
%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command "(Get-Content 'outfile.txt') -Replace 'svn', \"`nC:\Projects\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe\" | Out-File -Encoding Default 'outfile.bat'"
```

I do not often use single quotes, preferring to stick with double quotes, which means inside a double quoted command, I'd need to escape all of them, not just the one containing the new line designator:

```sh
%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile "(Get-Content \"outfile.txt\") -Replace \"svn\", \"`nC:\Projects\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe\" | Out-File -Encoding Default \"outfile.bat\""
```